# HTML offsetwidth

Tags: javascript, offsetwidth

Can someone list the properties that make up `offsetwidth`?

Also I need to calculate the offsetwidth be retrieving all these properties through javascript and summing them up. The sum of all these properties needs to be equal to the `offsetwidth`.

The code needs to be compatible with IE7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a way to determine the browser's scrollbar width

```
// adapted from http://davidwalsh.name/detect-scrollbar-width
function getScrollBarWidth() {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.style.width = '100px';
    container.style.height = '100px';
    container.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    container.style.position = 'absolute';
    container.style.top = '-9999px';
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    var width = container.offsetWidth - container.clientWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(container);
    return width;
}
```

You will also need a way to determine if the element has a verical scrollbar, then you just need to add up all the widths!

```
function getOffsetWidth(element) {
    var hasVerticalScrollbar = element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight &&
        !(element.style.overflow && element.style.overflow == 'hidden');

    var style = getComputedStyle(element);

    var offsetWidth = (parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('border-left-width'))) +
        (parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue('border-right-width'))) +
        element.clientWidth +
        (hasVerticalScrollbar ? getScrollBarWidth() : 0);

    return offsetWidth;
}
```

Here is a polyfill for `window.getComputedStyle` in IE7/8 - http://snipplr.com/view/13523/

Here is a working jsbin - http://jsbin.com/iboharI/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements
http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle

Comment: @Kavun thank you for the answer! I will test this out when I get a chance and let you know. Tks!